# Showing an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x, y]$ is not principal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I want to show that the ideal $I = (x^2, y)$ in the ring $R = \mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ is not a principal.  Any ideas?

Comment: If $I$ were equal to $(f)$, the polynomial $f$ would have to divide both $x^2$ and $y$.

Comment: @user49640 sorry you are right.

Comment: @user49640 To finish the argument, $f$ dividing both $x^2$ and $y$ forces $f = 1$ or $-1 $ in which case $(f) = R$.  Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. I mean, to justify your argument, there's a little bit less to prove if you already know that $Z[x,y]$ is a unique factorization domain. (Though it's easy either way.) After that, you still also need to prove that $(x^2,y)$ is not equal to $R$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $ $ If $\,(x^2,y) = (f)\,$ [then](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20136/242) $\,f = \underbrace{ \gcd(x^2,y) = 1}_{\large {\rm by\ prime}\ x\,\nmid\, y}$ so $1 = x^2 g + y h\,$ $\Rightarrow1 = 0$ by eval at $x,y = 0$