# Why the polynomial $1$ does not lie in $\langle x,y \rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ideals

I am trying to prove that $K[x,y]$ is not principal, $K$ a field.

I have taken in consider the polynomial $I=\langle x,y \rangle$. If $I$ is principal, then $I=\langle d\rangle$, for $d \in K[x,y]$. But in this case $d$ is a unit, it contains $1$ and hence $\langle d\rangle=K[x,y]$.

Now I have to show that $\langle d\rangle$ is distinct from $\langle x,y \rangle$. I think to prove this by showing that the polynomial $1$ does not lie in $\langle x,y \rangle$. If $1$ lies in $\langle x,y \rangle$, then $1=px+qy$, for some $p, q \in K[x,y]$, but I cannot arrive at a contradiction.

Would you help me, please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: what can you say about the global degree of $px + qy$ ?

Comment: *principal*, not principle.

Comment: @Batominovski Thank you! I corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constant term of $px+qy$ is $0$ not $1$, because every term has at least one $x$ or $y$ in it.

Comment: Thank you! So, the degree of (px+qy) cannot be zero, since every term contains at least one x or y in it contrary to the degree of 1 which is zero.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $ $ If $\,(x,y) = (f)\,$ [then](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20136/242) $\,f = \underbrace{ \gcd(x,y) = 1}_{\large {\rm by\ prime}\ x\,\nmid\, y}$ so $1 = x g + y h\,$ $\Rightarrow1 = 0$ by eval at $x,y = 0$

Comment: $x$ is prime by $K[x,y]/(x) \cong K[y]$ a domain, and $x\nmid y $ else $xf = y\,\Rightarrow\, 0 = 1\,$ by eval at $\,x,y=0,1$